How was Rabban Gamliel’s successor chosen?
Rabban Gamliel held of office of Nasi (patriarch) and was deposed. His successor was chosen to be Rabbi Elazar ben Azarya (Berachot 27b-28a). R' Elazar was a Kohen and therefore could not have been of the same family as the Nasi, nor could he have been a descendant of the line of David.
I would like to understand how/why R' Elazar was able to be chosen for this role (rather than either appointing someone else from the family of the Nasi or leaving it vacant until R' Gamliel died).

R' Elazar ben Azaria was appointed as an exception because he was wise, wealthy, 10th generation after Ezra (good yichus), and because he grew grey hair (so that his wife would agree) as gemara states. Gemara Berakhos says that after Rabban Gamliel apologized to Rabbi Yehoshua and other rabbanim on daf 28a, he was reinstated:

The question arose what to do with Rabbi Elazar ben Azarya? They said: What shall we do? Remove him from his position. That is inappropriate as we learned a halakha through tradition: One elevates to a higher level of sanctity and does not downgrade. Therefore, one who was the Nasi of the Sanhedrin cannot be demoted. Let one Sage lecture one week and the other Sage one week, they will come to be jealous one of another, as they will be forced to appoint one as the acting head of the Sanhedrin. Rather, Rabban Gamliel will lecture three weeks and Rabbi Elazar ben Azarya will lecture as head of the yeshiva one week. That arrangement was adopted and that is the explanation of the exchange in tractate Ḥagiga: Whose week was it? It was the week of Rabbi Elazar ben Azarya. One final detail: That student who asked the original question that sparked this entire incident was Rabbi Shimon ben Yoḥai.

He was Rabban Gamliel II of Yavneh. His grandfather Rabban Gamliel the elder was installed as Nasi by R' Yochanan ben Zakkai after the destruction of the Temple. His father was Rabban Shimon ben Gamliel. After Rabban Gamliel II, his son R' Shimon ben Gamliel II was appointed as a Nasi.
As far as yichus of the family of Hillel being descendands of David haMelekh as stated in Bereshis Rabba 98:8

Hillel, from whom did he descend? Rabbi Levi said: A genealogical scroll was found in Jerusalem in which it was written: Hillel is from David. Rabbi Ḥiyya Rabba is from Shefatya son of Avital.

or conflicting account in Kesubos 62b:

It is related further that Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi arranged for his son to marry a daughter of the household of Rabbi Ḥiyya. When he came to write the marriage contract, the girl died. Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi said: Is there, Heaven forbid, some disqualification in these families, as it appears that God prevented this match from taking place? They sat and looked into the families’ ancestry and found that Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi was descended from Shefatya ben Avital, the wife of David, whereas Rabbi Ḥiyya was descended from Shimi, David’s brother.

or Shabbos 56a

Rav said: Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi, who descends from the house of David, seeks to teach the verse in favor of David.

That is only true on their mother's side. According to Yerushalmi Kilaim 9:3 and Yerushalmi Kesubos 12:3, the direct descendant of Rabban Gamilel II, his grandson Rabbi Yehuda haNassi, explicitly stated himself that he was from Shevet Binyamin on his father's side:

Rebbi was very meek and said, all a man might ask from me I am ready to do, except what the elders of Bathyra did for my ancestor: they divested themselves of their presidency and appointed him. If Rav Huna, the Head of the Diaspora, would come here I would let him sit higher than myself since he is from the tribe of Judah and I am from Benjamin, he is from the male line and I am from the female.

Rav Huna, the Head of the Diaspora, the exilarch, was a direct descendant of the exiled king Yechoyakin (Eliyakim) and obviously of David. Thus, the yichus of Rabban Gamliel was not as strong of a factor.

R' Levi Ginzberg in his chiddushim on Yerushalmi argues that in fact R' Gamliel was never 'deposed' from the Patriarchy (Nasi) but merely from being the head of the academy (Rosh HaYeshiva).
This accords with the language of the Talmud where R' Elazar is asked

נִיחָא לֵיהּ לְמָר דְּלֶיהְוֵי רֵישׁ מְתִיבְתָּא
Would you like to be the head of the Academy

As well as the continuation that when R' Gamliel was 'restored' R' Elazar continued to give the Shabbos derasha (on certain weeks) as they were now co-Roshei Yeshiva

+1 interesting observation.
